# Is this a valid proof re: Banach Fixed Point Theorem and Lipschitz continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis

The question posed is the following: Let $X$ be a Banach Space  and let $T:X\to X$ be a Lipschitz-Continuous map. Show that, for $\mu$ sufficiently large, the equation
\begin{equation}
Tx+\mu x=y
\end{equation}
has, for any $y\in X$, a unique solution.

Note that $x,y$ are vectors, since our book (*Mathematical Analysis* by Mariano Giaquinta and Giuseppe Modica) generally ignores vector indicators, since it's all multivariable.

My proof is based on the Banach Fixed Point Theorem:
Since $T$ is Lipschitz-continuous, we have $\|Tx\|\leq k\|x\|$ for $0<k\leq1$. So
$\|Tx-\mu x\|\leq k\|x\| - \mu \|x\|$.

Then we can say

\begin{equation}
\|Tx-\mu x\|\leq (k-\mu)\|x\|
\end{equation}

So, if $\mu$ is large enough that $|k-\mu|<1$, we have a contractive map, and by the Banach Fixed Point theorem, there exists a unique fixed point $x_0$ for $(T-\mu)x$. Then, $Tx-\mu x=y$ has a unique solution, namely, $x_0$.

My question is whether this is a valid proof. I'm mostly foggy on if I applied the theorem correctly, and if I am allowed to say $Tx-\mu x=(T-\mu)x$, since $T$ is a map and $\mu$ is a constant (I think).

Comment: What does $Tx \le kx$ mean? Both sides are vectors

Comment: Hm, good point. I believe the definition for vectors is in relation to the norms. I'll correct the statement.

Comment: For the record, the notation $\overrightarrow x$ (or $\vec x$) has been abandoned, if it ever existed, in mathematics textbooks. To the best of my knowledge, at least.

Comment: You cannot assume $k \le 1$. Further, Lipschitz continuity is a different property than $\|Tx\| \le k \|x\|$. Please look it up.  Also, the inequality  $\|Tx - \mu x \| \le k\|x\| - \mu \|x\|$ cannot be correct. Think about what this means for $\mu > k$.

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood Lipschitz-continuity apparently. So, we can say $\|Tx_1-Tx_2\|\leq k\|x_1-x_2\|$, for $k>0$. Since this is matrix-vector multiplication, I'm pretty sure I can say $\|T(x_1-x_2)\|\leq k\|x_1-x_2\|$ If we let some $x=x_1-x_2$, can I then say $\|Tx\|\leq k\|x\|$?

Comment: The above comment should be "where $k>0$". Not "for all"

Comment: $T$ is a Lipschitz continuous map. Nowhere is it said that it is linear, much less matrix´vector multiplication ($X$ can have infinite dimension.).

Comment: If $T$ is a map, but not (necessarily) a matrix, and $x$ is not necessarily a vector, then what does the notation $Tx$ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as 
$$
x=\frac1{\mu}\,(y-Tx)=Gx,
$$
and show that $G$ is a contraction for large enough $\mu$.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my final answer for reference:

Let $Gx=\frac{1}{\mu}\left(y-Tx\right)$. Then
\begin{align*}
    |Gx_1-Gx_2|&=\left|\frac{1}{\mu}\left(y-Tx_1\right)-\frac{1}{\mu}\left(y-Tx_2\right)\right|\\
    &=\frac{1}{\mu}\left|Tx_1-Tx_2\right|\\
    &\leq \frac{1}{\mu} k |x_1-x_2|\tag{For $0<k\leq 1$}
\end{align*}
Then for $\mu > k$, $G$ is a contractive map, and by the Banach Fixed Point theorem, has a fixed point $\bar{x}$ such that $G\bar{x}=\bar{x}$.

Then $G\bar{x}=\bar{x}=\frac{1}{\mu}(y-T\bar{x})$, and thus the equation $Tx-\mu x=y$ has the unique solution $\bar{x}$.