# prove uniqueness Lipschitz-continuous map in Banach space

Tags: analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $T:X \rightarrow X$ be a Lipschitz-continuous map. Show that for $\mu$ sufficiently large, the equation
$$Tx + \mu x = y$$
has, for any $y \in X$, a unique solution.

Here is what I did:
Suppose there are two solutions $x_2, x_1$, then consider 
$$d(y,y) = 0 = d(Tx_2 + \mu x_2 ,Tx_1 + \mu x_1)$$
Since we are in Banach space, the metric is simply the norm:
$$0 = \vert \vert  Tx_2 + \mu x_2 - Tx_1 + \mu x_1 \vert \vert \leq \vert \vert  Tx_2 -  Tx_1 \vert \vert + \vert \vert  \mu x_2 - \mu x_1 \vert \vert $$
By definition of Lipschitz-continuous map, there exist a $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$d(Tx_2 , Tx_1) \leq M d(x_2 , x_1)$$
Thus we have 
$$0 \leq (M+ \mu)\vert \vert x_2 - x_1 \vert \vert$$
And now let $\mu < -M$, we reach the contradiction. is this somehow valid? I am not that confortable that $\mu < -M$ is sufficient large, what if $M>0$....

Also, I dont know how to prove there is a solution exists.

Comment: Your proof of uniqueness is not right, since when you look at $\|\mu x_2 - \mu x_1\|$ and pull out the $\mu$ from the norm, you are assuming $\mu \geq 0$.

Comment: @WillieWong ok I see that now

Comment: @WillieWong still have no idea how to do this tho.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this a valid proof re: Banach Fixed Point Theorem and Lipschitz continuous function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946379/is-this-a-valid-proof-re-banach-fixed-point-theorem-and-lipschitz-continuous-fu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic application of [Banach's fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

> **Banach fixed point theorem** If $F:X\to X$ is such that there exists $\lambda\in [0,1)$ such that for every $x_1, x_2\in X$,  $\|F(x_1) - F(x_2)\| \leq \lambda \|x_1 - x_2\|$, then there exists a unique fixed point of $F$.

Consider the function 
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\mu} (y - Tx) $$
A solution to your original equation is also a fixed point of $f$. So if we can show that $f$ is a contraction mapping (equivalently it is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $<1$), then by Banach's fixed point theorem we are done.

But
$$ f(x_1) - f(x_2) = \frac{1}{\mu} [T(x_2) - T(x_1)] $$
so as long as you choose $\mu$ bigger than the Lipschitz constant of $T$ you have that $f$ is a contraction mapping.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.